# Как получить параметры компонента из другого компонента

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Имею следующую структуру в router.js

```
  this.route('provider', {
    path: 'provider/:provider_name'
  }, function () {
    this.route('forms');
  });
```

В provider/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  inject: { service }
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  provider: service(),

  model(params) {
    return this.get('provider').get(params.provider_name);
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return { provider_name: model.get('name') };
  }
});
```

В provider/forms/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  inject: { service }
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  forms: service('provider.forms'),

  model(query) {
    return this.get('forms').getPage(query);
  }
});
```

**Как я могу получить provider_name в модели forms?**

Сделать что-то в provider/forms/route.js типа

```
model(query) {
  return this.get('forms').getPage(query.provider_name);
}
```

Или каким-нибудь другим путем получить provider_name.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться методом [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) объекта `Route` для получения родительской модели. Т.е. в дочернем(`forms`) `route` Вы делаете так:

```
model(query) {
  return this.get('forms').getPage(this.modelFor('provider').name);
}
```

Это будет работать при условии, что модель возвращаемая из родительского `route` содержит свойство `name`. Замените этот `name` на то, что Вам удобнее.